# ScrollView Not Working Above and Below of LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am new to Android. I am stuck in xml. I made a layout and its looking and working fine.[Click Here For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b4iI.png)

Xml Code for the above Image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:src="@drawable/back_50" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="App Logo"
        android:gravity="center"
         />


    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_services"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Trainings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.63"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.21"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="February"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="02.12,  LinkedIn,  @11:00am"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="02.26,  Business Excellence,  @11:00am"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.21"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/middle1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="March"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/middle2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="03.11,  Facebook Advertising,  @1:00pm"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/middle3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="03.25,  Personal Branding,  @11:00am"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.21"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="April"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="04.08,  Email Marketing,  @11:00am"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="04.22,   Twitter for Business,   @11:00am"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.12"
    android:background="@color/yellow_dark"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/instagram"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/instagram" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/vimeo"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/vimeo" />


    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

But now I used ScrollView for scroll if data will be increased in future and i am not able to do that. I am posting image and code below.

[Click Here For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnAnC.png)

Xml Code where I add the ScrollView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:src="@drawable/back_50" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="App Logo"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_services"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Trainings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.63">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.63"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="February"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="02.12,  LinkedIn,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="02.26,  Business Excellence,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="March"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="03.11,  Facebook Advertising,  @1:00pm"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="03.25,  Personal Branding,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="April"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="04.08,  Email Marketing,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="04.22,   Twitter for Business,   @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.12"
    android:background="@color/yellow_dark"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/instagram"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/instagram" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/vimeo"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/vimeo" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want my layout as the above 1 by using scrollview. Thanks

Comment: Try by adding "android:fillViewport="true"" attribute to your scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your xml as follows :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:src="@drawable/back_50" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="App Logo"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_services"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Trainings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.63"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="February"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="02.12,  LinkedIn,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="02.26,  Business Excellence,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="March"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="03.11,  Facebook Advertising,  @1:00pm"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="03.25,  Personal Branding,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="April"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="04.08,  Email Marketing,  @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="04.22,   Twitter for Business,   @11:00am"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.025"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0.12"
    android:background="@color/yellow_dark"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/instagram"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/instagram" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/vimeo"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/vimeo" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following attribute to your scrollView:-

```
"android:fillViewport="true"
```